# zxing integration into monodroid app

Tags: c#, android, barcode-scanner, zxing, xamarin.android

I'm trying to integrate ZXing's barcode scanner into a MonoDroid application. I see that normal Android (java) apps have [IntentIntegration.java and IntentResult.java](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/#zxing/integration/android) to include into their project to help. I was wondering if anyone has ported those to .NET (I didn't see them ported in the csharp project.)? I'm also wondering if anyone has implemented ZXing in another way to get to work with their app? If anyone has integrated with MonoDroid, what needs to be done to initiate a scan in a button click handler?

Also, if anyone has any other 3 party barcode scanner that could be implemented instead, put those suggestions in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

The first question is, do you actually need to port those files? :-)

You can include Java source code into a Mono for Android project; just set the Build action to `AndroidJavaSource` and the source will be compiled into the resulting .apk. This can also be done with `.jar` files.

Then comes the question of [invoking the Java code from C#](http://mono-android.net/Documentation/API_Design#Jave_Native_Interface_Support).

In the case of `IntentIntegration.java` and `IntentResult.java`, that *may* be enough, as those types don't support inheritance (they're `final`). Granted, using [JNIEnv](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Runtime.JNIEnv) to invoke methods on them would be a PITA, but it can be done:

```
// Untested code, provided for demo purposes:

// Handle of the Java class we're invoking
IntPtr IntentResult = 
        JNIEnv.FindClass("com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator");
// Handle of the method to invoke
IntPtr IntentResult_initiateScan = 
        JNIEnv.GetMethodID(IntentResult, "initiateScan", 
            "(Landroid/app/Activity;)Landroid/app/AlertDialog;");
            // method signature can be obtained from `javap -s`
// Invoke the method; return value is an AlertDialog instance
IntPtr rAlertDialog = JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (
        IntentResult, IntentResult_initiateScan, new JValue (someActivity));
// ...and construct a nice managed wrapper over the Java instance.
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog (rAlertDialog);
```

Furthermore, the `IntentIntegrator` docs mention that the Activity provided must override the [Activity.OnActivityResult](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Activity.OnActivityResult(System.Int32%2cAndroid.App.Result%2cAndroid.Content.Intent)) method.

All that said, porting `IntentIntegrator.java` shouldn't be *that* difficult, as most of it is a wrapper over [Activity.StartActivityForResult](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Activity.StartActivityForResult(Android.Content.Intent%2cSystem.Int32)) with an appropriate intent and construction of an `AlertDialog` (which you may or may not need).

Comment: if you know for sure this works let me know. I switched from MonoDroid to the true Android SDK (except I use JetBrains' IntelliJ studio) as this was a must for me to have ZXing work.

Comment: jonp, I did not understand the signature parameter of the GetMethodID method. I have not been able to run javap on the intentintegrator.java as it keeps complaining that it cannot find the class. Please help. Could you explain the signature component?

Comment: @CF_Maintainer: The easiest way is to use `javap -s -classpath filename.jar package.of.some.Type`. However, if you have a `.java` file and not a `.jar` file, I'd suggest compiling into a `.class` file and using `javap`; otherwise, you need to manually deduce the JNI signature: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432 and http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html

Comment: @jonp. Thanks a bunch. I was able to get your code to bring up the zxing dialog. Only thing I had to fix was the GetMethodID to GetStaticMethodId on the initiateScan call. Do you think working with google map ovrlays will be tedious in mono droid?

Answer (score 0):

We now have `ZXing` ports for `MonoTouch` and `Monodroid`.
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile