# Does MonoDroid work with Zebra Crossing?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, zxing

Does MonoDroid work with [Zebra Crossing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)?

If not, is there a C# alternative that I can use? Where do I find the C# port that I can use with MonoDroid and C#?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [zxing integration into monodroid app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614830/zxing-integration-into-monodroid-app).

Answer (score 0):

There is a component listed at Xamarin.com that is a manual port of ZXing.

http://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile/

The author did a talk at Evolve and the library is fairly robust yet simple to use... plus it is open source and free.